# C++ - How to specialise a custom type for std::max without overloading comparison operators?

Tags: c++, templates, max, generic-programming, std

I'm looking for advice on how to implement a specialised "max" (i.e. maximum) function for a custom data type that also works with scalar types like `float`. The data type I'm writing is a wrapper for a vector (eventually a SIMD vector of four floats, not a `std::vector`) and I want to provide a `max` function to compare two vectors and return a new vector that is the maximum of each element. This is different to `std::max` which uses the comparison operator but the concept is the same.

The problem is that I have a generic function called `do_max(T x, T y)` that applies `max` to the inputs. I need this function to work for both scalar float inputs (e.g. `do_max<float>(0.1f, 0.2f)`) **and** my vector class (e.g. `do_max<MyVector>(v0, v1)`).

Note that overloading MyVector's comparison operators is not an option because I'm using those with the SIMD intrinsics that are quite different: they create an integer vector containing 1, 0, -1 for each element comparison rather than returning a boolean result.

The code I have below does not compile unless you comment out the `float f0 = ...` line:

```
// compile with: g++ -std=c++11 max.cc -o max
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class MyVector {
public:
  MyVector(float x0, float x1, float x2, float x3) : storage_ { x0, x1, x2, x3 } {};

  friend MyVector max(MyVector lhs, const MyVector & rhs);

private:
  std::vector<float> storage_;
};

MyVector max(MyVector lhs, const MyVector & rhs) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < lhs.storage_.size(); ++i) {
    lhs.storage_[i] = std::max(lhs.storage_[i], rhs.storage_[i]);
  }
  return lhs;
}

template<typename T>
T do_max(const T & x, const T & y) {
  // if this is std::max then it won't compile for MyVector
  return max(x, y);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

  MyVector v0 { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 };
  MyVector v1 { 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1 };

  MyVector v2 = do_max(v0, v1);

  // Comment out the following line to successfully compile.
  // However I'd like this to work for scalar types too:
  float f0 = do_max(0.1f, 0.2f);

  return 0;
}
```

I have a feeling I need a way to make that `max` function resolve to `std::max` for scalar types, and my specialised `max` friend function for the MyVector type.

How to I define a max function that works in this way? Is it better to forget about `std::max` and use my own max function that is specialised for `MyVector` and also provides implementation for scalar types like `float`?

The background for this is that I'm implementing a data path that I hope will work with both MyVector and scalar types (as a parameterised type at compile time). I already have arithmetic working, however the solution for `max` will be used with other functions like `min`, `exp`, `pow` as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Classic solution:

```
template<typename T>
T do_max(const T & x, const T & y) {
  using std::max;
  return max(x, y);
}
```

Argument-Dependent Lookup finds your `max`, for `float` this does not happen and you get `std::max<float>`.

Comment: Do you know why this fails if I replace `return max(x, y)` with `return max<T>(x, y)`? In this case, it looks like the compiler resolves it as a call to `std::max<T>(x, y)` and fails with an invalid operands to the `<` operator when `do_max<MyVector>` is instantiated. I don't understand why making the type parameter explicit on `max` would change this behaviour.

Comment: Your function isn't a template? max<T> is an explicit template instantiation.